# How to test Licensing Google Play without publishing the application

Tags: android, licensing

I have added Google Play Licensing with my app. As I read through the document to test this features, I need to publish the app in play store at least as alpha release. I was wondering for the development phase is there any other way like sandbox kind of thing where we can test the Licensing?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to publish to at least alpha to test right now. But your alpha track can have no users, and it won't appear in search in the Play store.